# Where are the VSCode error logs for extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When I get an extension error I have no way of knowing why the error happens.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

From what I know there are no dedicated logs for extensions. When you are debugging your extension you can write notes to the console. However, when you have problems with an installed extension this won't help. But keep in mind vscode is kinda "web browser", so it has the usual browser developer tools (see Help -> Developer Tools),

[image]

which will show you runtime errors (and all the other stuff those tools allow usually, including the entire vscode DOM). That's probably the best option you have in such a scenario.

[image]

And for extensions that use previewHTML (or web views) there's a similar goodie, but tailored towards HTML development. Use ctrl/cmd+shift+P to open the command pallet and type "Webview Tools". Select the match to open a similar view like the one described in the first paragraph. But this one is only for the previewHTML content and allows you to debug that! This view is only available when a page containing a web view/previewHTML is active and closes automatically when the web view tab is closed.

Comment: I don't think this helps too much. I had the similar situation (popup: "Kubectl command failed" without any further indication), and the Developer Tools of Chromium don't help. Most of the people will not develop extensions, but use them. So, no answer at all, I don't understand all the votes.

Answer (score 158):

You're probably looking for:

`cmd-shift-p` -> Search `Show Logs` -> `Extension Host`

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, I was looking for these logs too

Comment: unfortunately I get notification error when I click extension button, but there are no new logs

Comment: For me the best route was cmd-shift-p, then search Developer: Open Extension Logs Folder.

Comment: If you're using remote development (e.g. over SSH), click on `Remote Extension Host` instead.

Answer (score 20):

Another easy way is to select "Output" in the terminal window (open it from menu "Terminal" > "New Terminal" if it is not already open).
Then, use the scrolling menu on the right side and select what you need.

[image]

Comment: This seems like 100% the correct answer to me

Comment: Are those stored in any file? The non extension logs are put into files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46373762/where-are-visual-studio-code-log-files but I can't see the non-extension ones there :-( It would be easier to browse files for large logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own log streams in the `Output` panel using [`vscode.window.createOutputChannel`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/common-capabilities#output-channel)