# Where are Visual Studio Code log files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VS Code frequently shows an error, something like "Error: cannot read property 'name' of undefined". The 'ESLint' tag in the status bar also shows up in red with an exclamation mark.

I suspect my team's custom ESLint plugin. I'd like to see the stack trace of the failure, which would probably confirm or refute my theory.

Does VS Code keep logs for this kind of error? If so, where are they?

(I'm running it on a Mac.)

Answer (score 52):

VSCode has a couple of commands for opening its logs folders. For the VSCode logs, you can use the `Developer: Open Logs Folder` command, and for VSCode extensions it's `Developer: Open Extensions Logs Folder`. You can search for those commands in the Command Palette in the usual way.

These commands spawn a new Finder window on OSX, or open in Windows Explorer on Windows.

Comment: This should be selected as the best answer.

Comment: @SFDCDev27 it unfortunately doesn't help when VS Code won't start

Comment: For me on VSCode v1.65.1, command is `Developer: Open Extension Logs Folder`. Singular 'Extension'

Answer (score 25):

On Linux there are some log files under `~/.config/Code/logs`.

Answer (score 17):

On Windows, it is at `%AppData%\Code\logs`

Answer (score 11):

I believe this is the directory you're looking for on MacOS: `~/Library/Application Support/Code/logs/`. I'm not sure if extensions typically store their logs and stuff elsewhere, but they'll likely be somewhere in the `Code` folder.

Comment: This is where I found the logs from an extension I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

For clarification if anyone else stumbles on this, type `>Developer: Open Logs Folder` with the`>` symbol to start

Comment: This is useful, the other responses, though correct, are incomplete for providing a good explanation

Answer (score 5):

You can use the VSC [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#:%7E:text=The%20most%20important%20key%20combination,for%20the%20most%20common%20operations.).

VSC stores its logs in various files depending on the purpose of those logs. There are a few commands to view them.

1. View the logs in your editor with the command:

   ```
   >Developer: Show logs
   ```

   Then select which log file you want to view.

OR

2. View the log files in your file navigator with the command:

   ```
   >Developer: Open Logs Folder
   ```

*Screenshot of command pallet log options*
[image: command pallet: >developer show logs]