# vscode: how to redisplay notifications that I hid/dismissed?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I want redisplay I hide notice in the past

Comment: Open the settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-click the bar at the bottom that contained the notifications icon and then click on the option "Notifications" to check it and make it display again.

**BEFORE**

[image: Notifications icon not displayed]

The notification sign will be showing again:

[image: Notifications icon displaying correctly]

Comment: It's not clear from the question, but I'm thinking that the OP wants to see notifications that they had seen and then dismissed (as opposed to removing/adding the notification bell icon from the bar).  That's what I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

If the OP is referring to viewing notifications that they had seen and dismissed, e.g., a log or history of notifications, then this might be relevant:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/96838

Also related: [Where are Visual Studio Code log files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46373762/where-are-visual-studio-code-log-files)

I did a recursive grep in `~/Library/Application Support/Code` (on a Mac) for text from a notification I had seen, and there were no matches.