# in vs studio spring boot maven project is not loading it shows Failed to create a project. Failed to fetch metadata

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-extensions, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am installing all extensions whatever required for spring boot maven project and i checked all things like proxy internet connection, network, disabled firewall setting but it is not working again and again it shows an error.
[image: failed to fetch metadata]

Comment: could you please add more details, such as logs? I'm no VS code expert, but you could try some advice from this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46373762/where-are-visual-studio-code-log-files; then please add those logs to your question, so that we know what failed to download. Thanks!