# rubocop on VScode not working.Error "rubocop is not executable"

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, rubocop

Recently I installed rubocop on vscode. However, it doesn't work.Error message is below.

```
rubocop is not excutable 
execute path is empty! please check ruby.rubocop.executePath
```

How should I fix it? I searched some articles, never solved...

cf. vscode-ruby-rubocop
https://github.com/misogi/vscode-ruby-rubocop

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### tl;dr

Make sure you installed Rubocop in the first place.

### VS Code Rubocop Tutorial

#### [Install Rubocop](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/)

```
gem install rubocop
```

You can check that it works properly like this:

```
rubocop -v
```

#### Install VS Code extension

Search for [`ruby-rubocop` in the marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=misogi.ruby-rubocop) and install it.

[image: Install Rubocop VS Code marketplace]

#### Configure Rubocop for your project

Add a `.rubocop.yml` file to your project's root. You can see all the configuration options and how such a file should look like in the [default config file](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/blob/master/config/default.yml). Be aware that if there are outdated or wrong rules in the file, you will get an error and Rubocop won't work. VS Code will alert you about this:

[image: Rubocop config errors]

Answer (score 71):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. However, I did find a comment by `jdarnok` on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby/issues/338) that worked for me.

First, to get the user's path of the program file, I ran:

`rbenv which rubocop`

which gave me this result:

`/Users/<your username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/gemsets/Rails4.2_EnergyLink/bin/rubocop`

Then I ran:

`which rubocop`

which gave me this result:

`/Users/<your username>/.rbenv/shims/rubocop`

**SOLUTION**

In the settings of VS Code under `Ruby > Rubocop: Execute Path` I pasted:

`/Users/<your username>/.rbenv/shims/`

*Other potential solutions*

This [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247926/how-to-solve-usr-bin-env-ruby-executable-hooks-no-such-file-or-directory) refers to a few other potential solutions, such as:

- Replace `bin` in the PATH with `wrappers`
- Refresh `executable hooks`
- Update bundler
- Update gems

Comment: `Replace bin in the PATH with wrappers` seems to have worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome ;) (jdarnok)

Answer (score 14):

Take a look to the [configuration docs](https://github.com/misogi/vscode-ruby-rubocop#configuration).

```
{
  // If not specified searches for 'rubocop' executable available on PATH (default and recommended)
  "ruby.rubocop.executePath": "",
  ...
}
```

So, by default `executePath` won't be setted, because it's expecting you to have the rubocop executable within your PATH.

In a simply way, there are two things you can do, add the rubocop executable path to your PATH, or add it within the package options.

You can check for the rubocop executable directory with `which rubocop` (then copy and paste).

Comment: Thanks! I tried `$ which rubocop`, then `rubocop not found`, when `$ rbenv which rubocop`, then `Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/rubocop` returned. So, how should I set the path to `ruby.rubocop.executePath` ?

Comment: It would seem your shell isn't running the `rbenv` version of Ruby you have installed. What does `rbenv list` or `rbenv versions` list (I use `rvm`, don't know the commands, sorry) as opposed to `ruby -v` or `which ruby`? I would think that switching to `rbenv 2.5.1` then running `code .` from your terminal would help VScode find `rubocop`.

Comment: Sorry for replying late... Thanks to your advice! It worked!

Comment: running `code .` from terminal like @t56k mentioned worked for me as well. I am running ruby with RVM and had the similar issue on a M1 air.

Comment: running code . also worked for me. Thank you for it.

Answer (score 11):

**Short answer**: Try starting VSCode a different way.

**Explanation**: A process inherits all the environment configuration it was started from. If rubocop is installed in your global environment, then, great no matter how you start VSCode rubocop will be available to the plug-in. On the downside, rubocop is now available to everything, most of which will never need it, and all the things that do use it need to require the same version of rubocop.

If rubocop was installed in a gemset using a ruby manager, or you have something like a dot-file manager that manipulates your environment, rubocop might not be in the PATH when you start VSCode.

I start VSCode from the terminal, always. I open a terminal and `cd` into my project folder. My ruby manager (rvm) and dot-file manager (direnv) automatically add and change some variables in the environment. Then I run `code .` to start VSCode with my project. This ensures VSCode is running in the same environment configuration as my app will run.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into this issue, it was because the version my bundle wanted and the version that rubocop in vscode wanted were different.

In the vscode rubocop settings, checking `execute rubocop using bundler (ie 'bundle exec rubocop') and eliminating the execute path worked for me. [Ruby > Rubocop: Use Bundler checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xUwS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error. Problem is that VS Code hides the detailed errors.

To see the full error and help with solving the issue:

> Open Help -> Developer Tools -> Console ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44188262/where-are-the-vscode-error-logs-for-extensions))

There you will see the actual error.

I had 2 broken cops that had to be updated and also the executable path was wrong.

Very annoying but if you open the Dev tools and check the console, you will be able to debug much better and solve whatever issue arises.

[image: Screenshot of VS Code with Debug Console]