# Prettier not formatting HTML files in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Prettier extension on my VS code is unable to format HTML.

On load of VS code I am getting this error in my console -

[image]

On trying to format, I see this message in the bottom -

[image]

Note - TS files and SCSS files are being formatted properly. It is breaking only for HTML files.

Below is my HTML language based settings -

```
{
  "tslint.rulesDirectory": "./node_modules/codelyzer",
  "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib",
  "window.zoomLevel": 0,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "files.associations": {
    "*.html": "html"
  }
}
```

These are the extensions installed and enabled -

[image]

Prettier version - `2.2.2`

VS Code version (from About VS code section) :

```
Version: 1.38.1
Commit: b37e54c98e1a74ba89e03073e5a3761284e3ffb0
Date: 2019-09-11T13:31:32.854Z
Electron: 4.2.10
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 17.7.0
```

Please let me know how to get this issue fixed. Please leave a comment if any more info is needed. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any error traces for when you run the formatter? Perhaps you can start with using a minimal amount of HTML in the file until you get the problem?

Comment: Tried with only `<div>  </div>`. Getting the same error. How do I get the error trace? I suspect that prettier is not being run for HTML files.

Comment: I checked on how to debug extensions, your best bet is probably enabling [developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6phws.png) so you can take a look at what issue is causing the error. Referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44188262/where-are-the-vscode-error-logs-for-extensions).

Comment: There's also cmd-shift-p -> Search Show Logs -> Extension Host (from the same question)

Comment: @Enthus3d I already check the developer tools console. There are no errors here when I format a HTML file, but on startup there was one error whose screenshot I have already attached in the question. Now I checked the Show Logs > Extension Host. No errors here while formatting HTML files

Comment: Hmm, I suspect that that error is causing an issue for your extension service, which results in the side effects. Perhaps you could try fixing that particular issue first to see if it helps. Other than that, it's difficult for me to say what could be going wrong. You could attempt to post your problem on the vscode [issues thread](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) if you're not able to get the help here. Best of luck!

Comment: "Prettier version - 2.2.2" looks rather old to me. My current version is 5.1.3.

Comment: I should reinstall vscode then check formatOnSave again

Comment: **Check out this answer on StackOverflow:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586965/why-does-not-prettier-format-code-in-vs-code/67017050#67017050

Comment: @Henke has the best answer. It's a vs code issue. Just re-install extension before do anything more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Prettier not format code in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586965/why-does-prettier-not-format-code-in-vs-code)

Comment: I hope you'll accept the answer here?

Answer (score 148):

Same for me. I managed to solve it as follow:

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
    }
}
```

This allowed me to use prettier globally and use built in html formatter for html.
Also allowed the formatting to happen on save and while typing.

The part responsible for Prettier formatting html

```
  "[html]": {
            "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
        },
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround ! Just to be clear, that's solving HTML file not getting proper formatting but it's not Prettier that will format. We default to VSCode formatter. On Prettier v5.6 and enable globally.

Comment: Worked for me. I had the prettier and eslint config files set up and my config.json had js and other stuff but not html

Answer (score 38):

I got the same issue, the cause can be updating the VS Code.
fixed it by setting the Default Formatter of Text Editor

Go to Settings (`Ctrl+,` for windows), search for 'Default Formatter'

Set the formatter in dropdown (esbenp.prettier-vscode) for prettier. this can change if you are using any other formatter.

Comment: Fixed my problem. I also needed to restart my VS Code. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 13):

**Short Answer:**

1. open Prettier from the button on right bottom corner
2. scroll up to see error list.
3. fix the wrong semantic you wrote.
   ex:
   [photo for error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLGaO.jpg)

**Long Answer:**
Most of the times the reason why Prettier doesn't work is that you have a markup error.

ex: you haven't close the angle braces or you close the tag more that one time
to know the error and fix it : look at short answer.

Comment: it works for me. I have fixed the wrong simantic of </link> tag.

Comment: It worked for me. thanks. i was searching for about 3 hours and after your answer i just tried to find an semantic error. I found it and now prettier works again

Answer (score 12):

Firstly, you may want to solve the compilation error you have in regards to Vue.js. You may need to grab some extensions for VS-code as detailed [here](https://github.com/xabikos/vscode-javascript/issues/49).

I have heard that Prettier has some issues formatting HTML at times, and VS Code itself already has HTML formatting support. You can stop prettier from formatting HTML specifically using the following command:

```
"prettier.disableLanguages": ["html"]
```

You could also change this line in your configs to enable VS code html language support instead.

```
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
}
```

Comment: I did check out the [issue](https://github.com/xabikos/vscode-javascript/issues/49). But it doesn't mention how to disable it without installing any extensions. Since I am not using vue, I dont need any extensions.

Comment: Also I would not want to disable prettier for HTML. I would want to go with the prettier setting for HTML formatting since that is what other developers in the team are using. This helps in achieving the consistency in formatting among all the developers in the team.

Answer (score 7):

For me i found that prettier was refusing to format files, however there was no errors in the output window in vs code. usually this happens when the html is not valid: missing tags, or tags closed twice, or tags that are not closed.

To see the errors, i ran prettier from the command line, and for each file it refused to format, it showed an error of what was wrong, like in the image below:

[image]

Comment: For reference, the command is like `npx prettier -c index.html`

Answer (score 6):

Had this problem crop up today after working fine with HTML previously.

Tried editing default formatter, format on save, reloading prettier etc.

Eventually tried the solution proposed above

edit settings.json

make sure   "[html]": has default formatter line set to the below, found it on line 40.

```html
"[html]": {
            "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
        },
```

Answer (score 4):

Disabling `"editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modifications"` fixed the issue for me in Angular's `.component.html` files.

Answer (score 3):

Simple and easy way to make it work.

Steps:

1. Open VSCode, go to Settings (`Ctrl+,` for windows), search for `Default Formatter`
2. Set the formatter in dropdown (**esbenp.prettier-vscode)** for prettier. this can change if you are using any other formatter.
   [image]
3. Extra step, if you want to use it **on the save file**. Just search for `Format on save`, then check that it is **TRUE**
   [image]
4. Restart your VSCode, and Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

I had a lot of problems with getting Prettier to format on save. It turned out to be an issue with the default timeout settings in VSCode. Using these settings finally worked for me:

```
{
    ...
    "editor.codeActionsOnSaveTimeout": 100000,
    "editor.formatOnSaveTimeout": 100000,
    ...
}
```

For reference, here are all my settings concerning linting and formatting:

```
{
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": { "source.fixAll": true },
    "editor.codeActionsOnSaveTimeout": 100000,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnSaveTimeout": 100000,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
    "eslint.enable": true,
    "html.format.enable": false,
    "htmlhint.enable": true,
    "prettier.requireConfig": false,
    "prettier.useEditorConfig": true,
    "stylelint.autoFixOnSave": true,
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    },
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    },
    "[json]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    }
}
```

I use the following extensions (again limited to linting/formatting):

- ESLint (dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)
- Prettier (esbenp.prettier-vscode)
- stylelint-plus (hex-ci.stylelint-plus)
- HTMLHint (mkaufman.htmlhint)

You might want to make sure that all the npm packages needed by your extensions are installed. Locally if possible.

I sincerely hope this helps. Setting up linters and formatters is still a science in its own right.

P.S. I get an error like your 'cannot format' message whenever I try to format a file that is not inside the working directory. But looking at the path in your message suggests that this is not an issue in your case.

Answer (score 2):

If the formatting fails, see if there are any errors in the Prettier console.
If not, use the following settings:

```
  "[html]": {
    // "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
  },
```

Once the file has been formatted, put back the original settings:

```
  "[html]": {
    // "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
  },
```

And try formatting again. This time Prettier will have better input to work with.

The `requirePragma` option should be false (it is by default) in `.prettierrc` or VS code  prettier settings (dotfile overrides VS).

Answer (score 2):

I simply solved it by right-clicking in the file, select 'Format Document with' and choose 'prettier'. I don't know how to permanently set it up but it's a quick workaround.

Comment: This was the best answer I tried the rest.  The reason it works is it rewrites the settings.json file direclty.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me.

In the settings.json, capitalize the `h` in `[html]`:

```
...

"[Html]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},

...
```

Comment: that's weird, it works for me. not sure why vscode has changed the settings like this

Answer (score 1):

`prettier` formatter doesn't support  `Format on selection` or `Formate On Save` for HTML files - `modification` mode, So for this, you can set `formatOnSaveMode:'html'` for HTML files in `settings.json`

```
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file"
  },
```

Format selection works on several languages depending on what Prettier itself supports. The following languages currently are supported:

```
javascript
javascriptreact
typescript
typescriptreact
json
graphql
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to check the notifications in the bottom right corner. Once I clicked on it, you can configure which formatter to use. For some reason, there are more than one editor. I'm gonna go on a limp and assume that it's conflicting somehow with the editors global config file.

[image: Notification Icon]

Answer (score 1):

I just changed the default formatter for HTML to VScode's HTML formatter.

1. Open the command palette with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (or use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> for Mac).
2. To open the user `settings.json` file search for and select the `Open User Settings (JSON)` option.
3. Make the following changes.

```
   // "[html]": {
   //     "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
   // },
   "[html]": {
       "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
   },
```

Answer (score 1):

To update the default HTML formatter in Visual Studio Code (VS Code), follow these steps:

1. **Open Settings**: Press `Ctrl` + `,` (Comma) or navigate to `File` > `Preferences` > `Settings(JSON)`.

[image: iii]

2. **Edit JSON Settings**: Locate the relevant section, such as `[html]`, where you can set the default HTML formatter. Replace it with the following code:

```
  "[html]": {
            "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
        },
```

3. **Save Changes**: After making the edits, save the JSON file by clicking the disk icon in the top-right corner of the JSON editor or pressing `Ctrl` + `S`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  "[Html]": {
    //"editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  this work for me
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the bottom of my VSCode User settings did the job for me:

```yaml
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found Prettier to be annoying sometimes with HTML. Hence in my case this worked for me for HTML formatting-

user json file settings as follows-

```
 "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter"
  },
```

For HTML I use **JS-CSS-HTML Formatter** extension in VSCode as the default formatter (as you can see in code above). This formats the HTML code well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by navigating to the settings (ctrl + shift + ,)
type in the search **default format**
then check HTML -> format: enable box

Answer (score 0):

To open the command palette, you can use COMMAND + SHIFT + P on macOS or CTRL + SHIFT + P on Windows.

In the command palette, search for format and then choose Format Document.

You may then be prompted to choose which format to use. To do so, click the Configure button. Then choose Prettier - Code Formatter or another prettier code formatter.

Your code is now formatted with spacing, line wrapping, and consistent quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this one; Create the file `.vscode/settings.json` in your root project with this config:

```
{
    ...
    "[html]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    },
    ...
}
```

For other types of files, us the same block but change `html` with the language you want, for example `typescript` or `scss` etc...

Answer (score 0):

In vscode:

- right-click in an empty space inside the html document,
- then select: format document with
- then select: html language features.

Answer (score 0):

For me none of the answers I tried worked at the moment I tried them (before writing this) so I found a weird solution.

I'm not entirely sure why it works or what is wrong (imagine there was some api update to vscode that Prettier hasn't adopted and this option bypasses that as the action is from prettier not integrated the editor.action.formatDocument way), so be warned.

1. In VSCode: `Shortcuts` > `Format Document (prettier.forceFormatDocument)`
2. Set the keybinds that fit your preference (I use `shift + alt + f`)
3. (Optional) Just to make sure you aren't accidentally using it outside of the relevant documents set the when condition (right click to access this) to `editorHasDocumentFormattingProvider && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && !inCompositeEditor && editorLangId == 'html'` which only adds the `&& editorLangId == 'html'` section to ensure this is only active whilst inside an html document.

You may also want to add  `|| editorLangId == 'css'` to that when condition as well if you have this issue for css. The same things apply.

Do note that this unfortunately as far as I can tell does not allow for partial document formatting as might be relevant if you work in a large group of people. It also will not respect ignore files, so if these matter to you this is a partial fix.

That being said, as a bonus, if you leave it as your default html formatter, now you wont get that error message, and you can still use features like formatting on save. Quite a bang up workaround.

Answer (score -1):

One of my peers installed the following into the workspace vscode:

"prettier.disableLanguages": ["html"],

That would do it.

Answer (score -1):

Use This as your config

```
"prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "prettier.useEditorConfig": false,
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[css]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[jsonc]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

### Try restarting VS Code

I've had Prettier stop formatting things when VS Code prompted me to restart to update. Closing and opening VS Code got it working again.