# Intellisense not autocompleting variables in HTML

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Intellisense for html in my VSCode has stopped working. I'm able to get the autocomplete for html tags, but I'm not getting suggestions for .ts variables. I've always used this feature and for some reasons it's not working anymore. For ts files it's working correctly.

VSCode version: 1.60.2

Installed extensions:

- Angular Language Service
- Angular spec generator
- OpenAPI (Swagger) Editor
- Reload
- SVG Viewer
- TODO Highlight
- Visual Studio IntelliCode
- YAML

I don't remember installing one of those and then intellisense for html stop working. I've tried restarting VSCode and the language shown in the bottom bar of VSCode is the right one.

Comment: That's my problem too. I'm coding from memory in the last month

Comment: have you tried disabling all the plugins except Angular Lanugage Service ? and if that works just start enanbling one by one until it stops working.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and fixed by disabling and then re-enable the Angular Language Service extension.

1. Disable the Angular Language Service.
2. Reload VS Code.
3. Enable the Angular Language Service.

This worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me, no idea why. Good ol' turn it off and on again.

Comment: XD ahaha this works but sounds so stupid.

Answer (score 2):

Try enabling "Force Strict Templates" in your Settings. I am on Angular 15. Now I see the autocomplete for nested objects in the HTML. Adding `strictTemplates` in my `tsconfig.json` did not work as suggested by the documentation.

[image: "Force Strict Template" option in VSCode Settings]

Answer (score 0):

In order to get full angular variable autocomplete feature inside your html file we need to tweak some setting in our workspace `tsconfig.json` file, Please perform the following steps :-

1. Open `tsconfig.json` file of your angular project workspace.
2. set  `strictTemplates` flag to `true` in your `tsconfig.json` file.

```json
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictTemplates": true   
},
```

3. Restart your Visual studio code and then check if suggestion are coming inside your html file.

This is also stated in Angular language plugin's [official info page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template).

[image]

Comment: Let me know if that worked for you and accept my answer if working fine.

Comment: That didn't work, I already had strictTemplates in my file but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling all the plugins except Angular Lanugage Service ? and if that works just start enabling one by one until it stops working.

Also have you checked the logs of the extensions ?
[Where are the VSCode error logs for extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44188262/where-are-the-vscode-error-logs-for-extensions)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed by disabling and then re-enable the Angular Lanugage Service extension.

1. Disable the Angular Lanugage Service,
2. Reload VS Code
3. Enable the Angular Lanugage Service.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed both Angular Language Servcie and Angular Snippets (Version 13) thats why problem occurs. then i uninstall Angular Snippets (Version 13) and restart Angular Language Servcie and restrat vs code.and now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete `/.angular` folder in Angular project root. This worked for me when other suggested solutions hadn't worked.

`/.angular` folder is safe to delete because it will be re-generated on build. It contains cache of compiled project which I thing sometimes can get corrupted after you make too many changes (especially after changing your project verion or using npm link to local dependency libs and rebuilding those libs, at least in my experience those kind of changes sometimes (rarely) caused some intellisense or even compilation problems that were only solved by deleting `/.angular` folder).