# VScode auto adding types

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I'm getting auto-insert types everywhere. Can't find what extension is doing it. Is it IntelliSense? How can I disable it?

Comment: the actions of extensions can be logged, see: [Where are the VSCode error logs for extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44188262/where-are-the-vscode-error-logs-for-extensions)  (and it is possible to log more than just errors)

Answer (score 0):

first, go to your extensions list by pressing Ctrl+Shift+X or clicking the extension's icon, then you can see your installed extensions and determine which one is causing this.
To disable an extension click on it and then click disable.

Answer (score 0):

They are called *"inlay hints"* and they are not the types but the names of the corresponding function arguments (the first argument of [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#syntax) is called *"string"*.)

They need to be enabled in the editor to show up (*Settings* -> *Editor* -> *Inlay Hints*).

Then, each extension that provides inlay hints has its own settings to configure when they are displayed.

Search for *"inlay hints"* in the VSCode settings and decide for each extension what hints to be displayed (or disable the functionality globally from the *Editor* -> *Inlay Hints* setting.)

Your code looks like JavaScript, check for the inlay hints in the settings of the TypeScript extension.