# No definition found in VS Code for Nuget packages referenced from F#

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#, nuget, ionide

How to enable F12 to Go to Definition of Nuget assembly in Visual Studio Code in F# files?

In this particular example, I added Playwright nuget package, but can't see it's API via F12, whereas 'Go to Definition' command works fine for all standard .NET libraries.

[image]

Comment: I am seeing this behavior too. Have you tried opening the extension log to see what errors are being reported? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54381900/7392598

Comment: I can navigate to definitions of some nuget package functions (e.g., JsonConvert.SerializeObject from Newtonsoft.Json works just fine) but when I try to use Playwrite.CreateAsync I get an error logged (`Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.Text.Json, Version=6.0.0.0...`)

Comment: @Tenatus Thanks for pointing out, I see `[error] Error: Error while decompiling symbol 'Method ("Microsoft.Playwright.Playwright", "CreateAsync", [], 0)' in file 'C:\Users\maksi\.nuget\packages\microsoft.playwright\1.39.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Playwright.dll': Failed to resolve assembly: 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
Resolve result: <not found>`